# SSL connections very slow to localhost IIS 8 but work fine from non-local initiating connection

Tags: ssl, localhost, iis-8.5

As the title says, I have a web server on which ssl connections initiated from the local server are extremely slow - 1 minute+ time to load even a hello world txt.  Non-ssl connections are not affected.  However the same pages/files/web services are served up as expected with little to no delay from any non-local source connection.

For clarification, by local host I mean including domain name, loopback IP as well as assigned network IP.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port Address Translation and an SSL redirect on our F5 was the root cause.  　  /sigh to IT that makes changes without notifying application support, development or product management.